# Make Visual Studio Emulator for Android connect through mobile broadband adapter of host machine

Tags: android-emulator

I am starting visual studio emulator for android, and it works fine when I am in a wlan or lan network.

But my laptop (which is running windows 10) has also a mobile Broadband adapter. When I am connected with the internet through this device, the emulator does not detect any internet.

Tp fix this I am tried to add a Virtual Switch to in the Hyper-V Manager with an external network. But the only external networks I can select are my wlan and my lan adapters. The Mobile Broadband adapter does not show up.

Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: The question suddenly moved from Android Emulator connectivity to Hyper-V Virtual Switch!

Comment: Made a Small edit for clarification

Comment: I don't have answer! Broadbands usually add a second wireless network adapter to the laptop in windows and that messes withe every applications network settings